# Unable to Json Decode

Tags: php, json

I seemed to be stuck with JSON Decode , i dont know how to decode the json object or maybe im doing something very wrong , iam doing :

```
$error_fields_structure['product_id'] = $this->input->post('product_id');
$error_fields_structure['main_product_quantity'] = $this->input->post('quantity');
$error_fields_structure = json_encode($error_fields_structure);
```

i pass $error_fields_structure to my view and in my java script i do:

```
<?php print_r(json_decode($error_fields_structure)); ?>;
```

i get an error in firebug and following output

```
 stdClass Object
(
[product_id] => 62
[product_quantity] => 65
);
```

but if i do

```
 <?php print_r(json_decode($error_fields_structure['product_id'])); ?>;
```

it gives me a null string and an error
how do i get particular product_id and product_quantity from json object $error_fields_structure

Comment: what javascript has to do with it? and if so what is your firebug error?

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: also , i wanted to decode the json in javascript which is possible as given in the documentatio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only decode a valid json string.

```
<?php print_r(json_decode($error_fields_structure['product_id'])); ?>;
```

is incorrect as $error_fields_structure['product_id'] is not a json string.

Try this :

```
<?php 
$errorFieldsArr = json_decode($error_fields_structure,true);  //convert json string to array
var_dump($errorFieldsArr['product_id']); // get element from array
 ?>
```

or

```
<?php 
$errorFieldsArr = json_decode($error_fields_structure);  //convert json string to stdobject
var_dump($errorFieldsArr->product_id ); // get element from object
 ?>
```

Comment: Pathak

how can i assign the json array(converted) to a java script array ?

     var demo = new array();
     demo = <?php (json_decode($error_structure,true)); ?>
how can i do something like that ?\

Comment: you should just decode the json in your javascript code instead of in your php code, you can use jquery to make it easier